# How to call package procedure from DB link

Tags: sql, oracle, dblink

I have 2 DB link. One is the default. Currently, I have,

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure SP_MySP(Params);
is
begin

   PackageName.Object (Params);
end;
/
```

The above one works fine for the default package. Now I need to call the same object on another DB link. I am doing,

```
SELECT PackageName@MySecondDbLink.Object (Params) FROM DUAL
```

Now I getting the error,

```
ORA-04054: database link XX does not exist
```

Comment: The link name comes *after* the procedure you're invoking - so `SELECT PackageName.Object@MySecondDbLink(Params)` should do it for you.

Comment: Check the docs: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm. "Use only ASCII characters for dblink. Multibyte characters are not supported. The database link name is case insensitive and is stored in uppercase ASCII characters." So oracle have no chance to know if "Object" in "MySecondDbLink.Object" is not a part of DB link

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica You are great :)